# concatenate values within for loop to use outside the loop

Tags: php

I'm building a website which has product details and images stored in 2 different tables. I don't want to join the tables, so I have 2 queries that grab the details.

What I have done is passed the `product id` to grab all the images. The problem is, I want to  store all the image urls in  `$img_block` so i can display the product details and all the images, except for the first product. All the other products contain the previous images of the products.

```
product 1 : image p1-1 and image p1-2
product 2 : image p1-1 image p1-2 image p2-1
product 3 : image p1-1 image p1-2 image p2-1 image 3-1
```

My Code:

```
foreach ($products as $key=>$product):

$images = $this->control_model->product_images($product['pid']);

            foreach ($images as $image):

            $img_block .='<img src="'.$image['url'].'" height="75px" width="75px">' ;

            endforeach;

$msg .= '<div class="one_half_full">
            <div class="listbox">
            <div class="list_text">

            <h4 style="font-weight:bold"><a href="#">'.$product['title'].'</a></h4>
            <p>
              <div class="clearfix" id="images"> 
               '.$img_block.'
              </div>';

endforeach;
```

Can someone please let me know how can i concatenate the correct image urls?

Comment: you're missing `';` after the last `div` before the last `endforeach`

Comment: awful style of coding: foreach(...): endforeach;

Comment: @UnholyRanger thanks for spotting it mate. Dont know how i missed it..

Comment: @vladkras learning php :) any other good way?

Comment: foreach($array as $foo => $bar){ //doStuff }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initilize the `$img_block` like : (I add the final quote...)

```
foreach ($products as $key=>$product):

$images = $this->control_model->product_images($product['pid']);
$img_block = '';
            foreach ($images as $image):

            $img_block .='<img src="'.$image['url'].'" height="75px" width="75px">' ;

            endforeach;

$msg .= '<div class="one_half_full">
            <div class="listbox">
            <div class="list_text">

            <h4 style="font-weight:bold"><a href="#">'.$product['title'].'</a></h4>
            <p>
              <div class="clearfix" id="images"> 
               '.$img_block.'
              </div>';

endforeach;
```